# List<ClassName> returned to PHP from WCF Soap Service

Tags: c#, php, wcf, soap

I am working on a project and I have a WCF self hosted service in a console app. I then have PHP project which access the soap service and returns an array of type `List<SoapHandler.EmailStatus>`. Below is how the data is returned when I print_r it to the browser.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [getRamInfoResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [SoapHandler.RamInfo] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ramFree] => 3
                    [ramTotal] => 7
                )
        )
)
```

I can't figure out how I can access the data within the SoapHandler.RamInfo i.e. echo ramFree and ramTotal.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$ramFree = $ret->getRamInfoResult->{"SoapHandler.RamInfo"};
```

where `$ret` is your soap return value